# How to conditionally use a "content_for" wrapper in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, haml

I am trying to find a more DRY way to do the following:

```
- if request.xhr?
  :javascript
    {my javascript}
- else
  = content_for :scripts do
    :javascript
      {my javascript}
```

I reuse this pattern in many Haml files, so I am wondering what is the best way to abstract-out the conditional logic. Ideally, I'd like to achieve something like the following in my Haml files:

```
optional_content_for :scripts do
  :javascript
    {my javascript}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to solve my need, in case anyone else has the same request...

```
def script_content_for(&block)
  if request.xhr?
    capture_haml(&block)
  else
    content_for :scripts, nil, &block
  end
end
```

Use:

```
= script_content_for do
  :javascript
    {my js}
```

Comment: Nice, and I'd make the :scripts into a variable, def xhr_content_for(name, &block)