# How can I DRY up conditional content_for in Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, layout, view, bootstrap-modal

contests/show.html.haml:

```
- if modal
  - content_for(:modal_header) do
    = render 'contests/contest_header'
  - content_for(:modal_body) do
    = render 'contests/contest_body'
- else
  = render 'contests/contest_header'
  = render 'contests/contest_body'
```

`modal` is a boolean local which indicates whether the view is being rendered in a modal template, vs the regular application template.  The modal has content_for blocks while the main application template does not:

layouts/modal.html.haml:

```
-modal = true
.modal-header
  .row
    .col-xs-11
      = yield(:modal_header)
    .col-xs-1
      %button{'type': 'button', 'class': 'close', 'data-dismiss': 'modal', 'aria-label': 'close'}
        %span{'aria-hidden': 'true'} &times;
.modal-body
  = render 'layouts/messages'
  - if content_for?(:modal_body)
    = yield(:modal_body)
  - else
    =yield
```

What I'm looking for is something that can conditionally make the content_for blocks disable when `modal` is false.  Rather than repeating my render statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from another SO answer!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27398070/378622

Here's my implementation

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def modal_content_for(name, &block)
  if params[:modal] == '1'
    content_for 'modal_' + name.to_s, nil, &block
  else
    capture_haml(&block)
  end
end
```