# How to use "if" condition in Haml for "content_for"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm using this code:

```
  - content_for :javascript do
    :javascript
      var test = 0;
```

I want to insert this code only under certain conditions using an `if` condition.

```
- content_for :javascript do
```

Otherwise, I want to insert this code:

```
:javascript
```

How do can I this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". While you might not speak English as a primary language, you can have someone proof-read for you, right? Stack Overflow isn't a message board or a forum, it's more like an online reference book, so grammar and formatting are important, for instance "wanna" is "want to".

Comment: We want to know what you tried to solve the problem. What did you do to work around the problem and why didn't it help? Edit the question and incorporate that into it as if you'd included it initially; don't use "edited" or "updated" tags as we can tell what changed when.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally use a "content\_for" wrapper in Haml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397560/how-to-conditionally-use-a-content-for-wrapper-in-haml)

Answer (score 0):

```
- if set_test?
 - content_for :javascript do
    :javascript
      var test = 0;
- else
  :javascript
```